# How to add and remove the Lightning button color for sales force lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to add and remove style for Lightning button after clicking the button.Iam trying apply css for Lightning button

```
 <lightning:button onclick="{!c.applyCSS}" aura:id="changeIt" label="Add Style" value="changeValue"  />

applyCSS: function(cmp, event) {
    var cmpTarget = cmp.find('changeIt');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'changeMe ');
}


.THIS.changeMe {
background-color:yellow;
width:200px;
```

}

Comment: Simply use `toggleclass` instead of  `addClass` . or you can use 'removeClass' and `addclass` combination to achieve this

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `toggleclass` instead of `addClass` . or you can use '`removeClass`' and `addclass` combination to achieve this

**Example**

**Controller:**

```
applyCSS: function(cmp, event) {
     var cmpTarget = cmp.find('changeIt');

     if($A.util.hasClass(cmpTarget,'changeMe')) {
         $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget,'changeMe');
     } else {
        $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget,'changeMe');
     }
}

or////////////////////////////////////////////////////

applyCSS: function(cmp, event) {
        var cmpTarget = cmp.find('changeIt');
        $A.util.toggleClass(cmpTarget, 'changeMe');
 }
```